# How can I make firefox refresh if I hit enter on the address bar and there's a fragment id in the url?

Tags: windows-7, firefox

If you go to any website (eg: `www.google.com`) and then modify the address bar so it ends in `/#` then hit enter, instead of refreshing the page it does no operation.  I'd like this to refresh the page.  Is there a way to configure firefox so this will refresh?

Comment: Why don't you just refresh the page?

Comment: I end up doing that.  But it annoys me that I realize after the fact that I need to do that.